# Keep User logged in on android webview (wordpress site)

Tags: android, wordpress, logging, webview

i have developed a wordpress website and I used webview for the android app.
now my concern is that whenever a user log in to the app and opens the app after closing the app.I want to keep them logged in !

Comment: WordPress has built-in functions to extend the logged-in cookie length, this might be a good starting point: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24597/how-can-i-increase-the-login-expiration-length

Comment: @Parth Any update on how you implemented this? We have a similar use case, hence looking forward if you found a valid solution, or if wordpress has any inbuilt apis for implementing this.

Answer (score 1):

two ways either save your user login username and  password to sharedprefrence and check it everytime or save your user login username and password to sqlite and check if cursor count is 1 then redirect to webview else type username and password.

Comment: can you tell me which one would be easy and simple and can you elaborate more about the same ?

Comment: shared prefrence would be simple.

Comment: I was not able to achieve with shared preference can you please show me some sample code about how to do that ? or can we use the cookie manager and then load cache from the local storage ?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and I solved it by enabling a cache for the App. You might be able to do so by adding this to your Webview instance in MainActivity.java:

```
//enable in-app cache
myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Hope this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

This is to be managed by wordpress side, and not in Android.

Answer (score -2):

cache is no good about security also if user when the close app on ios, the cache gonna be delete

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This looks more like a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45412695/2227743) rather than a new answer.

Comment: Dear, I totally agree with Eric Aya's Response, if you're commenting , please be sure to use comment section and if you have any solution please provide it with a clear and detailed response so it could be meaningfull. thanks